# injecting dependency into controller constructor or use a property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository

In our code base there is a base controller and a derived controller. In the base controller, which called `BaseController`, dependency where injected using properties like the below.

```
private IAuditRepository _audit;

protected IAuditRepository Audit
{
    get { return _audit ?? (_audit = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuditRepository>()); }
}
```

And the derived controller which inherit the base controller is also being inherited by multiple controllers. Lets say this derived controller is called `BaseProjectController`. This controller has a `ProjectRepository` so instead of following the same approach given in `BaseController` the orginal author of the codes inject this repository in the constructor, something like the below.

```
private IProjectRepository _projectRepository;
protected BaseProjectController(IProjectRepository projectRepository)
{
    _projectRepository = projectRepository;
}
```

So any controller related to `Project` will inherit the `BaseProjectController` and each controller would need to implement a snippet code like.

```
public class ProjectActivityController : BaseProjectController
{
    public ProjectActivity(IProjectRepository projectRespository)
     :base(projectRespository) { }
}
```

I find it easy to use the first approach and just call the property from the controller inheriting the `BaseProjectController` instead of needing to inject this in the constructor.

the question is why this approach when you can just follow the same approach in the `BaseController`? What is the difference of the two? Why would you choose the first approach over the second - vice versa?

Comment: One of the main arguments against the Resolver (Service Locator) approach is testability. But I'm guessing, from all the inheritance layers, you don't do much unit testing anyway.

Comment: There is a third option: remove the base class completely. Your `IAuditRepository` seems a cross-cutting concern and there are often more effective, and maintainable  ways to implement cross-cutting concerns instead of base classes. But in order to advice you, more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can describe pros and cons of both methods, so, you decide yourself.

### Constructor injections

Pros:

1. You see all dependencies in one place
2. No [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) anti-pattern - your code does not depent on specific container (DependencyResolver)

Cons:

1. You should pass all dependencies from child to base classes (a little more code to write)

### Property injections

Vice versa :)

So, compare pros and cons and make a decision.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong however for the Property injections I do not need to pass the dependencies from child to base classes. all I need is to call the property from the base class

Comment: @rpmansion as for me, i prefer constructor injections. It's more clear, I think